# order by sort wrong records

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table with `Subscription' , when I sort recordes with order by I getting wrong result . My Result Does not sort , by MyColumn

my query is :

```
Select Subscriptioncode from Subscription order by Subscriptioncode desc
```

my Result like as :

```
90
80
8
700
73
634
100
```

Why getting this Result ?

> In SubscriptionCode some Row is Null.

100

Comment: What's the data type of `SubscriptionCode`?

Comment: You're sorting strings, not numbers.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Your column `SubscriptionCode` is currently not a numeric type, and it is likely a text type instead.  However, you can `CAST` this column to an `INT` type and then the ordering should work with no problem:

```
Select Subscriptioncode from Subscription
order by CAST(Subscriptioncode AS INT) desc
```

Answer (score 3):

You should declare  **Subscriptioncode** column **Datatype As INT**

Example

```
create table Subscription(
Subscriptioncode  int)

insert into Subscription  values('90')
insert into Subscription  values('80')
insert into Subscription  values('8')
insert into Subscription  values('700')
insert into Subscription  values('73')
insert into Subscription  values('634')
insert into Subscription  values('100')


Select Subscriptioncode from Subscription order by Subscriptioncode desc
```

OUTPUT:

```
Subscriptioncode
700
634
100
90
80
73
8
```

**Note:**

As you are declaring datatype other than **INT** Ex:Varchar

-->**It will sort values  as like Sorting Alphabetical order** i.e)abc

that's y you are getting wrong results.so choose correct Datatype.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following to retrieve your data in descending order with order Nulls at end or at start(as you mention your column-name contain Null also)

```
select column-name from table-name order by case when column-name is null then 1 else 0 end,cast(column-name as int)desc
```

*It retrive the result as nulls at the end (for nulls at start change 1 to 0 and 0 to 1)*

If you don't want to specify nulls position then you can use

```
Select column-name from table-name order by cast(column-name as int)desc
```